# empty md-select after choose option

Tags: angularjs

This is my md-select

```
<md-input-container flex="50">
        <label>Choose user</label>
        <md-select ng-model="data.model" ng-change="sum(data.model)">
            <md-option ng-value="logins.name" ng-repeat="logins in chooseLogins">{{logins.name}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
```

Select works fine I get what I need but md-select is empty after "selecting".

It looks like get option then clear field.

Comment: What does "is empty after selecting" exactly mean?

Comment: Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/suunyz3e/1082/)... I don't understand why don't you see the selected option, probably is a problem of your `chooseLogins` array... show more code of your controller.

Comment: @The.Bear Check my jsFiddle and try to select user is empty after choose: https://jsfiddle.net/defuseer/mrp3qxgq/41/

Comment: Your problem is inside the `sum` method... I've updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/mrp3qxgq/57/) just removing the line which is cleaning the value of your model. I don't know about your logic, but take a look of that method :) ... Good luck

Comment: Hey,  thanks for response, but without this line I can't sum values. Try to choose for example Zac Doe and see what happening and also try uncomment it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you change your `md-select` model on `ng-change`. You shouldn't reassign that model. Try to mutate it instead if needed.

**EDIT:**

Well, you can't mutate model in your case, because it is string literal. So you just shouldn't reassign it and save `tests` variable on `change` event to somewhere else.

Comment: I can't do this by myself. I don't know how to "mutate" it.

Comment: well, I think you should change your program logic somehow. In your model you need to have user name, which is logical. But then you change it to absolutely different data. For example, model was `Mark Doe`, but becomes `{test: 41}`, which is weird. Not sure about your logic integrity, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/GProst/mrp3qxgq/65/) is my jsFiddle changes. Generally I changed `data.model` to `data.currentUser.name`, then on `change` event I save `tests` variable to `data.currentUser.dept`.